# Cloud function for check monitors status via API and send it to a Bigquery table

Tags: function, google-cloud-functions, postman, datadog

I need help creating a `Google Cloud function` that will retrieve the result of an `API` request, and integrate it into a `BigQuery` table.

I don't see any documentation on the internet, if anyone has already done it.

I tried a `cloud function` with `ChatGpt` help but its doesn't work (maybe too old).

My `API` request works with `POSTMAN`